# How to take out a value from subscribe function typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

After subscribing onto API I want to bind this data with htmlan HTML component, but I face difficulties. I want to know what's the good practice to do that

```
  getAllPosition() {
    let positions = [];
    this.apollo
      .query<any>({
        query: this.tpeService.filterTpeByRegion(),
      })
      .subscribe(({ data }) => {
        console.log("Data", data);
        data.filterTpeByRegion.map((item) => {
          let mapObj = { lat: 0, lng: 0 };
          mapObj.lng = +item.longitude;
          mapObj.lat = +item.latitude;
          positions.push(mapObj);
          // console.log(positions, "global");
          this.markers = positions;
          console.log(this.markers, "global scoop");
        });
      });
  }
```

In this function I want to take out the data from subscribe function still undefined
`

Comment: Make sure your tpeService is returning proper response.

Comment: Is `markers` undefined when you log it ?